# Angular app when to hold data arrays locally or on the server?

Tags: angular

I am designing an app that will provide the user with an ability to view/filter anything between 200 to 2,000 records.

The data volumes are small enough to bring the data back from the source rest service in one call. Having all the data stored locally will make the app lightening fast.

Is this a good idea or not?  Are their any best practice guidelines for deciding when to pull data on demand versus pulling it all in one block?

Comment: storing more numbers of record in local storage is not good idea. Better you add cache to API side. if no changes fetch same records

Answer (score 0):

Lets say 1kB per record - it is 2Mb for 2000 records.  This is very small amount for modern browsers/PC. (E.g. my current running Chrome takes 600+Mb of memory) So just store it anyhow - that wont impact anything.

Another story is html elements - e.g. 2 inputs per item will result in 4000 inputs, that will slow your browser, so for viewing you should use some kind of virtual list.